# Delete Single Message MSMQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, msmq

Is it possible to delete a single message from a MSMQ message queue ? I have a Queue object, a message (object) that I have got to by peeking and the ID of the message, I can see a way of deleting (or purging) the entire queue, but I can't see a way to delete the message on it's own, I've tried receiving the message once I have found it by peeking, but I get the error that "the cursor is invalid"

Any help gratefully received

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you trying to use `MessageQueue.ReceiveById`?

Comment: Damn .. I was trying to be to clever and recieve by my peek cursor on the queue .... recieveById worked just fine .. ta

Answer (score 2):

You could try [QueueExplorer](http://www.cogin.com/mq/index.php).

Comment: Thanks but I want to do it programatically

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the receive function. Depending on your language/technology ( c, com, .net ).

For .net it will be the MessageQueue.ReceiveById Method. Or any that you find appropriate. Depending on the message you want to remover (first, last, using cursor or id ).

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Language C#
    // Delete Message Button click handler.
    public void DeleteOneMessage()
    {
        // I created winforms application and added a reference to "System.Messaging"
        // Added one edit box name = queueNameTextBox
        // On Form_Load set queueNameTextBox.Text = @"private$\myQueueName"
        // Connect to the queue on the local computer.
        MessageQueue myQueue = new MessageQueue(queueNameTextBox.Text);

        // Set the formatter to indicate body contains an Order.
        myQueue.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();

        try
        {
            // Receive and format the message.
            object myMessage = myQueue.Receive();
            MessageBox.Show("One message removed from the queue.");
        }
        catch (MessageQueueException mqe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(mqe.Message);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```